# Back Population of VBA InputBox?

Tags: excel, vba

So currently under specific conditions I have this InputBox poping up for the user to enter notes into and then that box fill those notes to a cell. What I would like to try to do is if notes are already in the cell that the InputBox is filling notes to, those notes will already appear in the input field so that the user can add to them. I have no idea if this can be done and could not find anything on google. If this cannot be done ill just use a user form insted.

[image]

The current code that brings up the input box is below, "notes" is the feild that the InputBox fills to:

```
If InStr(OPs, "Incomplete") > 0 Or InStr(OPs, "Miss") Then
    notes.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 200, 0)
        If notes = "" Then
            Do While notes = ""
                notes = notes & InputBox("You must imput notes for " & Desc & " !", "Notes")
            Loop
        End If
End If
```

Comment: FWIW [`InputBox` function (Visual Basic for Applications)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/inputbox-function) shows up in the top 3 search results for "vba inputbox". Curious what your search terms were.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Default` parameter of `InputBox`:

Something like:

```
notes = notes & InputBox("You must input notes for " & Desc & " !", "Notes", notes)
```

However, if you use this, you don't want to use the `notes = notes & ...` as the string field will quickly overfill.. so perhaps just:

```
notes = InputBox("You must input notes for " & Desc & " !", "Notes", notes)
```